# Pending Intent only work for 1 alarm

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm, android-pendingintent

Currently, I have an alarm that works using pendingIntennt that works when a button(save an alarm) is pressed. The problem is, when I have multiple alarm scheduled and saved, the alarm that will go off is only the latest one. How can I make it so all the alarms will go off?

This is the code inside of the button:

```
public void saveReminder(View v) {

    final int reminderHour = mReminderTimePicker.getCurrentHour().intValue();
    final int reminderMinute = mReminderTimePicker.getCurrentMinute().intValue();
    final String reminderName = mReminderName.getText().toString();
    final boolean reminderStatus = mReminderSwitchSwitch.isChecked();

    //AlarmManagerHelper.cancelAlarms(this);
    //Updating Reminder Information
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyReminders");
    query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject reminderObject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                reminderObject.put("reminderName", reminderName);
                reminderObject.put("reminderHour", reminderHour);
                reminderObject.put("reminderMinute", reminderMinute);
                reminderObject.put("reminderStatus", reminderStatus);
                reminderObject.saveInBackground();
            }
        }
    });
    //set time into calendar instance
    GregorianCalendar calendar= new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,reminderHour);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE,reminderMinute);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND,00);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND,0000);

    AlarmManager reminder = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    Intent reminderintent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
    //push information to reminder screen
    reminderintent.putExtra("reminderName", reminderName);
    reminderintent.putExtra("reminderHour", reminderHour);
    reminderintent.putExtra("reminderMinute", reminderMinute);


    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1, reminderintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    reminder.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), operation);


    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same requestCode of 1 for all your alarms, and so each time you set an alarm, it overwrites the previous one when you call [PendingIntent.getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).

What you need is a way to have a unique ID for each alarm.

Using the `objectId` String, you could generate a unique ID by adding up all of the characters in the String:

```
    int id = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < objectId.length(); i++){
        id += objectId.charAt(i);
    }

    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), id, reminderintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    reminder.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
```

Comment: How do I call this method from the button click? I used   setArlarm(); and it doesn't work. I think I need to put some attributes in it. and Do I need to specify all atributes that will go into this method. such as: reminderHour, reminderMinute, userName, Tone, etc.? It will be a long list.

Comment: I use the android:onClick from the xml instead of writting the onClickListener. does this matter? I edited the code as shown

Comment: As you see in my code. I have all my alarms information go to parse. Do you think it's better to have the alarms go off using pendingIntent? or is there another way that is better to set off alarm when using parse database?

Comment: when I do that, the "int requestcode" inside the bracket of public void setAlarm becomes red.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83526/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-stanley-santoso).